# What is the purpose of the _loc variable when defining grammar rules in camlp4?

Tags: ocaml, camlp4

The `_loc` variable appears in [here](https://github.com/ocaml/ocaml/blob/trunk/camlp4/Camlp4Parsers/Camlp4OCamlRevisedParser.ml#L610) in the grammar rule for the `match ... with` expression as an argument passed to the `mk_sequence` function.

```ml
    | "match"; e = sequence; "with"; a = match_case ->
        <:expr< match $mksequence' _loc e$ with [ $a$ ] >>
```

But it is not used in the `mksequence`'s [function body](https://github.com/ocaml/ocaml/blob/trunk/camlp4/Camlp4Parsers/Camlp4OCamlRevisedParser.ml#L246).

```ml
  value mksequence _loc =
    fun
    [ <:expr< $_$; $_$ >> | <:expr< $anti:_$ >> as e -> <:expr< do { $e$ } >>
    | e -> e ]
  ;
```

The `_loc` variable also appears in [other](https://github.com/ocaml/ocaml/blob/trunk/camlp4/Camlp4Parsers/Camlp4OCamlRevisedParser.ml#L657) [places](https://github.com/ocaml/ocaml/blob/trunk/camlp4/Camlp4Parsers/Camlp4OCamlRevisedParser.ml#L653) in the grammar rules.

In the camlp4 code generation [tutorial](http://brion.inria.fr/gallium/index.php/OCaml_code_generation_tutorial#Defining_the_location), it says that `_loc` stands for location. But I don't quite understand the explanation there. Can someone explain to me the purpose for passing an unused `_loc` variable around?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Roughly speaking, `_loc` is "the current position". Normally it is bould to the location of the matched AST in parsing rules.

`_loc` is an ordinary OCaml variable, and actually omnipresent in CamlP4 code, but P4's syntax sugar nicely hide most of their existence. You can learn how '_loc' is introduced and used in P4 by preprocess your P4 module by P4. For example,

```
EXTEND Gram
  my_syntax:
    [ [ "match"; e = sequence; "with"; a = match_case ->
          <:expr< match $mksequence' _loc e$ with [ $a$ ] >>
    ] ];
END;
```

If you preprocess the above by `camlp4rf`, you got what it really means:

```
Gram.extend (my_syntax : 'my_syntax Gram.Entry.t)
  ((fun () ->
      (None,
       [ (None, None,
          [ ([ Gram.Skeyword "match";
               Gram.Snterm
                 (Gram.Entry.obj (sequence : 'sequence Gram.Entry.t));
               Gram.Skeyword "with";
               Gram.Snterm
                 (Gram.Entry.obj (match_case : 'match_case Gram.Entry.t)) ],
             (Gram.Action.mk
                (fun (a : 'match_case) _ (e : 'sequence) _
                   (_loc : Gram.Loc.t) ->
                   (Ast.ExMat (_loc, (mksequence' _loc e), a) : 'my_syntax)))) ]) ]))
     ())
```

It is bit hard but you can find `Gram.Action.mk` takes a function introducing an argument `_loc`. It is bound to the location of an AST which matches with the specification starts with `[ Gram.Skeyword "match"...`. Then `_loc` is used at `<:expr< match ... >>` which is expanded into `Ast.ExMat (_loc, ...)`, in addition to its second use at `mksequence' _loc e`, which is written by hand.

`<:expr<...>>` and the other `<:XXX<...>>` constructs in p4 uses this `_loc` variable so that you can create your AST without considering much about the location of it. It automatically uses `_loc`, "the current parsed location". If you do not want to use `_loc` for `<:expr<...>>` you can use `<:expr@myloc<...>>` to explicitly specify the location of your AST.

Sometimes you want to use `<:expr<...>>` outside of parsing rules, and in that case `_loc` is unbound. You must use `<:expr@myloc<...>>`, or use `<:expr<...>` after binding `_loc` by something else. Typically, `let _loc = Loc.ghost` which means "no where".

P4 is very complex, and there are not much documentations available in the net. Sometimes expanding your P4 code by P4 helps understanding how it works.

Comment: Thanks!

"Sometimes expanding your P4 code by P4 helps understanding how it works."

How do I expand my camlp4 code with P4?

Comment: Just as I wrote in the answer. camlp4rf <your file>, if you use the revised syntax (and you used the revised syntax in your question). camlp4of <your file> for the original syntax.